# If my capacitor plates have a high surface area due to porosity such as sintered metal. Can my capacitor plates be as thick as I want and hold charge?

Tags: capacitance

Say I have a capacitor plate. But this plate is made from sintered metal so it has a really high porosity and surface area. Does this mean I can increase plate thickness to any size I want due to the fact that the capacitor plate would have increased surface area with a thicker plate? Can my plate be 1 inch thick or even 12 inches thick? The plate separation distance would still be close say a few millimeters. Thank you I really need to know.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't work that way. The fact that capacitance is proportional to the plate area assumes that the plates are "smooth", or rather, that the plate separation is the same everywhere. If you were to etch holes or trenches on the surface of one plate to increase its surface area, you would find that the capacitance actually decreases somewhat. Intuitively, most of the charge collects in regions without holes (since they are closer to the other plate), which are smaller in total area than the original plate area, so the capacitance is reduced. In reality, the difference in capacitance between smooth and porous plates would likely be negligible, depending on the porosity and the plate separation.

Comment: no you’re wrong